# Send JSON data to sever - Javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, post

I have created a js file to get data from the form (text area) but I am not aware how to send this to server.

Could you please explain?

Here is my code

```
var myReview = element.myReviewTextarea.val();

      console.log("sendData()", "Sending data", { myReview: myReview });
      var promise = $.ajax({
        url: R.settings.endPoints.outgoing.sendData,
        type: "POST",
        data: {
          myReview: myReview
        }
      });
```

And I have some lines of code which receives data from json and I can see send data path is empty there. DO I need to create a json file and insert path there?

This is done by someone else and I am totally new to json.

```
endPoints: {
          incoming: {
            getData: "assets/js/tests/widgets/app-review-widget-test-data.json"
          },
          outgoing: {
            sendData: ""
          }
        }
```

Comment: you need to find out from the person thats giving you the json data. why is the outgoing url empty? obviously data will not send in that case

Comment: So it seems that you have an empty url? have you tried `sendData: "/some/url"`

Comment: empty URL would mean... the current directory?

Comment: That is my question, Do I need to create an json file for that if so what should be entered in that file to post the text area data to the server

Comment: json is just a data format. You are totally new to json when you've never seen it. Thus, you're not new to json ;)

Comment: You need to specify the url where you want to send you data. Try this `$.post('/path/to/file.php', {myReview: myReview}).done(function(){alert('...')}).fail(function(){alert('...')})`. Actually, here is the link: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON.stringify() method to convert json object into string

```
var myReview = element.myReviewTextarea.val();

      var datatosend = { value1: "1",value2: "2" };
      var promise = $.ajax({
        url: R.settings.endPoints.outgoing.sendData,
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(datatosend)
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON.stringify() will turn "datatosend" into a string so it's ready to be send to an external file

```
 var myReview = element.myReviewTextarea.val();
 console.log("sendData()", "Sending data", { myReview: myReview });

 datatosend = { endPoints: {
                  incoming: {
                     getData: "assets/js/tests/widgets/app-review-widget-test-data.json"
                  },
                  outgoing: {
                     sendData: ""
                 }
             }};

 $.ajax({
    url: R.settings.endPoints.outgoing.sendData,
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(datatosend),
    success: alert('Done!')
  });
```

I'm not sure why you saved the AJAX call as a variable...

Comment: Anywhere within the ajax call. Check my updated answer in a sec